# Redux Saga: Await Promise

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I have a promise that is already invoked and has to be awaited. Basically:

```
const foo = () => Promise.resolve('foo'); // The real promise takes time to resolve.

const result = foo();

await result; // This line has to happen in the saga
```

How can I await the pending promise? If I wrap it in `call` Redux Saga tries to invoke it and crashes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're in a saga, simply `yield` the promise. Redux saga will wait for it to resolve and then resume the saga, much like `await` would do in an `async` function:

```
const foo = () => Promise.resolve('foo');
const resultingPromise = foo();

function* exampleSaga() {
  const result = yield resultingPromise;
  console.log(result); // 'foo'
}
```

If the promise might reject, you can wrap it in a try catch:

```
try {
  const result = yield resultingPromise;
  console.log(result);
} catch(err) {
  console.log('promise rejected', err);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  const result = await foo();
  return result;
  // or just return foo() without await, as it is last statememnt in async func
}
```

Otherwise you can always do

```
foo()
  .then((result) => console.log('result', result))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```